# Setting environment variable to use localhost on server, and FQDN on dev machine

Tags: c#, .net, url, environment-variables

I have a .NET Core program that needs to run on some server ABC. Let's say the fully qualified domain name is `http://abc-service.com/`. In my code, I can call this service using `http://abc-service.com/api/v1/my-function`, this works ok when I'm testing this on my local machine, but when I deploy it to the server, it'll be on the same machine, so I should be able to use `http://localhost:port/api/v1/my-function`. Is there some sort of environment variable I can set so that the code knows to use the right path whether I'm testing on the right machine? I'm using .NET Core

Answer (score 0):

You should put environment specific variables in a configuration file, and have different config files for each environment. It removes dependencies between the objects. For instance, should you develop v2 of your API, you just update the config file to point to v2 and there is no need to recompile anything.